# Object in Blender turned into a grid [Blender]

Tags: grid, default, blender, transparent

I am new to Blender. I was creating an object and a skeleton when suddenly the object basically turned into a grid instead of showing off the default material.

[image]

How to make it look normal again ?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If the answer helped you, you should accept it...

Answer (score 2):

The 3dview has several [shading modes](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/display/shading.html) available, you have switched to wireframe mode.

You can switch back to solid or texture that you had before from the viewport shading menu.

[image: shading menu]

There are some shortcuts to change the shading mode. <kbd>Z</kbd> toggles between wireframe and solid shading which is most likely how you switched to wireframe shading, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> will toggle between solid and textured shading while <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> enables rendered shading in the viewport.